# Tokenizing using Pandas and spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tokenize, spacy

I'm working on my first Python project and have reasonably large dataset (10's of thousands of rows). I need to do some nlp (clustering, classification) on 5 text columns (multiple sentences of text per 'cell') and have been using pandas to organize/build the dataset. I'm hoping to use spaCy for all the nlp but can't quite figure out how to tokenize the text in my columns. I've read a bunch of the spaCy documentation, and googled around but all the examples I've found are for a single sentence or word - not 75K rows in a pandas df.

I've tried things like: 
`df['new_col'] = [token for token in (df['col'])]`

but would definitely appreciate some help/resources.

[full (albeit messy) code available here](https://github.com/LizMGagne/TIP_code/blob/master/TIP%20Stuff%20(2).ipynb)

Comment: Whats the specific issue you are having?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Peter I'm not getting an error, but the text doesn't seem to be tokenized (i.e. when I try to do further processing like lemmatization I get an error basically saying the text is still string format and not tokens).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've never used spaCy (nltk has always gotten the job done for me) but from glancing at the documentation it looks like this should work:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

df['new_col'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

Note that `nlp` by default runs the entire SpaCy pipeline, which includes part-of-speech tagging, parsing and named entity recognition. You can significantly speed up your code by using `nlp.tokenizer(x)` instead of `nlp(x)`, or by disabling parts of the pipeline when you load the model. E.g. `nlp = spacy.load('en', parser=False, entity=False)`.

Comment: How could we change the result in the column into list?

Answer (score 2):

Make it faster using pandarallel

```
import spacy
from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)    
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df['new_col'] = df['text'].parallel_apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```